# Data type returned by formdata in ajax

Tags: php, jquery

I have a simple PHP script that authenticates a user based on phone and password combination:

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

//Posted Variables

$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


//Check If User Exists

$result = $conn->query("select id from users where telephone='$phone' and password='$password'");
if($result->num_rows == 0) {
echo 'failure';
} else {
echo 'success';
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

I'm using `formData` to POST data to the server and I expect to use the data returned to decide whether a user is valid or not.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/android_login.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    crossOrigin: true,
    async: true,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
        if(data === 'success'){
        $("#login").trigger('reset');
        window.location.href = "app.html";
        }
        else{
        alert('Invalid Number Or Password.');
        }       
    },
    error: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { alert('failed');},
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

I am trying to do `if (data === 'success')`, then fetch `app.html` which is the dashboard or alert that the user did not provide valid phone or password.

Since jquery decides which datatype to expect, how can I test if data is equal to the string `"success"` or `"failure"`? I tried stringfying data but that didn't work either.

Comment: what do you retrieve if you make a console.log(data); ?

Comment: `if('success')` doesn't test against anything. That will just return true every time I think.

Comment: when i have the correct password and telephone i get success and if i have the wrong pairs i get failure.

Comment: "Since jquery decides which datatype". Not if you set the `dataType` ajax option yourself.

Comment: @ADyson i also tried if(data === 'success') too

Comment: that would make more sense. If it didn't work, you need to find out exactly what is in "data" at that moment to see why the comparison failed.

Comment: P.S. Your SQL query is vulnerable to injection attacks. You should use parameters and prepared statements to protect your data, rather than just concatenating strings.

Comment: what response you are getting when you use console.log(data)? Then depends on that use the condition.

Comment: P.P.S. `async:true` is redundant because that's the default value, and I seriously doubt you need `crossOrigin:true` - that's only if you're posting to the same origin but want, for some reason, to pretend that it's a CORS request. If the request is genuinely cross-origin, the browser will work that out for itself. If the request is genuinely _not_ cross-origin, then pretending it is just complicates matters, unless you have a very good reason to do so - possibly for testing, for instance.

Comment: There is also a potential security hole here because the PHP will return "success" even if the query failed to execute, and you aren't trapping errors as far as I can see. So it could authenticate a user just because there was an issue with the server. If anything it should default to failure. And you should be hashing/encrypting passwords, not storing them as plain text.

Comment: @RaghavendraRao when the password and telephone match console.log is success but the my code alerts failure. I have an update

Comment: @ADyson I am mostly in the testing phase, the passwords are in plain text i admit but hashing will be done later.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `dataType` from `text` to `html`:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://example.com/android_login.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: formData,
  crossOrigin: true,
  async: true,
  dataType: "html",
  success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    if(data === 'success'){
      $("#login").trigger('reset');
      window.location.href = "app.html";
    }
    else{
      alert('Invalid Number Or Password.');
    }       
  },
  error: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) { alert('failed');},
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false
});
```

Comment: Even if the password and telephone match, this gets execute alert('Invalid Number Or Password.');

Comment: what do you get in console.log(data);

Comment: @vaibhavraychura surely "text" would be a more appropriate data type? The response is just a string.

Comment: @jsjsjsjsjsjs have you verified that the values are passed to the server correctly, and that the query runs correctly? It feels like the problem is more likely to be there than in the response. You could be treating the symptom rather than the cause.

Comment: i recommend json or html data type and i know response is string but what is that exact string ?

Comment: i don't think you got 'success' string in response if you get then html dataType surely work

Comment: @Adyson I have verified everything, even hardcoded phone and password in the php script and verified it works. Its the client side that has that bug.

Comment: Turns out there were whitespaces in the response so i trimmed var res = $.trim(data); and it worked.

Comment: @vaibhavraychura why would you recommend a json or html data type when the response is neither of those things? Makes no sense.

Comment: @jsjsjsjsjsjs that would explain it. Strange that it put that space in, I've never come across that before. Unless it's to do with the data type. jQuery could be altering it somehow.

Comment: @ADyson I remember that error caused by returning data  from php laden with whitespaces but this is a plain php problem. When using laravel, the spaces are stripped away.

Comment: @ADysoni we have to change response according to dataType. i think it is common sense. now in this case if we use json datatype then we can easily detect white spaces.

Comment: In the condition '===' compares the data along with data type. Your data variable is of html type and you are trying to equal it to the string. Use '==' in your condition.

Answer (score 0):

As you have posted in one of your comments, your code "alerts failure". This all means your request is never going into "success" callback.

This can have multiple reason, first your ajax URL is probably wrong. Second, your script does return any other status code than "200". You can check all this in your browser console -> network panel (F12) when you make the ajax request.